Question about Perlin Vector Noise
I am new to Animation Nodes and I was trying to follow this whirlpool tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96MiJVJ9tdg
Early on the author uses a Perlin Vector Noise node that adds ripples into the surface of the mesh.
He must be using an earlier version because I cannot find that node in the hierarchy. the closest I can find is Vector Noise which doesn't output the correct data type. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Did you see the link to the Geometry Nodes version below the YT video and the further link on his updated video? - Animation nodes aren't used nowadays since the introduction of Geometry nodes and his tutorial has now been updated again here using Blender 4.2.

Yes, I discovered that link after I made this post and got it working. Thanks for the information, I appreciate the help.
